# Zurb Foundation 5 accordion not pushing content below down

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 and trying to include a menu inside of an accordion. When the accordion is clicked and expands it works fine but rather than pushing the below content down when opened, it opens over the background of the below content, but under the content of the below content.

I have tried to change the z-index of the accordion to 0 but it does not help. I have also added the clearfix class to no avail.

[Can be seen here](http://somethingtodonews.com/admin/dashboard.php)

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
 <div class="large-3 medium-4 columns hide-for-small sidebar-wrap" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 228px;">
```

You've set a fixed heigth for the container. Since it is already at max height, it can't expand further down.

remove `style="height: 228px;"` and everything gets pushed down. If you need a fixed height, so the content doesn't snap up and down everytime the user clicks on the accordion set it to `height: 402px;`. Thats the value Chrome tells me for 4 elements, with one expanded.

Comment: Thanks @Serv that is it... the height, however was being set by the equalizer widget which i was using to equal the heights of the sidebar and the content container... did not realize that was going on... nice snag... thanks again